# Search text area not updated using voice input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

currently I am using cordova based voice recognition for my search function.

HTML code:

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search"  ng-model="search" id="in" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click = "recognizeSpeechSearch()">
    <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.recognizeSpeechSearch = function(){
            var maxMatches = 1;
            var promptString = "Speak now"; // optional
            var language = "ms-MY";                     // optional

            window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(function(result){
                alert(result);
                    $scope.search = result;

            }, function(errorMessage){
                console.log("Error message: " + errorMessage);
            }, maxMatches, promptString, language);
        }
```

When i insert the input through voice, it will not updated on my search text area and perform search filter. Can someone assist me on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callbacks are executed outside of angular's scope.  You  need to use $apply():

```
    window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(function(result){
$scope.$apply(fuction() {
    alert(result); $scope.search = result;}) 
;}, function(errorMessage){ 
console.log("Error message: " + errorMessage); }, maxMatches, promptString, language);
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried $apply(); The text area can update with the input, but it cant perform search function

Comment: What do you mean you can't perform the search function? It's not executed?

Comment: I'm using angular filter function to perform the search, when i manually type in the input it can filter the item that match with keyword, when i using voice input, the text area can be updated but the filter function wont show any result to me.

Comment: Sorry, no idea why that's not working. Normally filters are called each digest cycle, and the $apply function calls for a digest, so I have no clue why there would be a problem there.